# Regex redirect every folder in upload except '2019'

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I am currently writing a rewrite rule in htaccess for all pdfs. I am a regex beginner but managed to get all the pdfs in wp-content/uploads/*/ to redirect to the start page.

How do i insert an exception. Like ignoring the files in wp-content/uploads/2019/*. Is that even possible?

My Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content\/uploads\/(?:(.+)\/)?(.+\.pdf) / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Would you try with `^wp\-content\/uploads\/(?!2019).*?\/.+\.pdf`?

Comment: After some testing this seems to work just fine! Thank you. I am taking a look at this regex with a tester to further understand it. Appreciate it!